# Unable to parse "April 10, 1999" to date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-date, date

I have date in `April 10, 1922` format, I want to convert this date to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` format, but first i want to convert this string into date.

I created a pattern for it, to convert this string to date.

```
private static String datePatternDOB = "MMMM d, yyyy";
dateConversionFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternDOB);
```

Then i parsed date.

```
dateConversionFormat.parse("April 10, 1922")
```

but got following exception.

> Method threw 'java.text.ParseException' exception.
>
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "April 15, 1932"
>   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the former in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("April 10, 1922", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString()` yields `1922-04-10T00:00Z`.